# How do I solve this equation: $(0.2)^{(-x+3)}=125^{(2x+3)}$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

I want to solve this equation: $(0.2)^{(-x+3)}=125^{(2x+3)}$.

The correct answer is $-2.4$, however I end up getting $12$.

I'm following these steps:

$(0.2)^{(-x+3)}=125^{(2x+3)}$

$125^{(3x-9)}=125^{(2x+3)}$

$3x-9=2x+3$

$x=12$

Comment: Can you explain me why $0.2^{-x+3} = 125^{3x - 9}$ ? When you pass from first to second line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $0.2=\frac15=5^{-1}$. So we have:
$$(5^{-1})^{3-x}=(5^3)^{2x+3} \Rightarrow 5^{x-3}=5^{6x+9}$$

and that's equivalent to $x-3=6x+9$.

Comment: Okay, thanks! However why isn't it possible to say 0.2=125^-3

Comment: Because it's not true: $125^{-3}=\frac{1}{125^3}$. You were trying to say $$0.2=125^{-\frac13}=\frac{1}{125^{\frac13}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{125}}=\frac15$$ and that is correct. You're welcome~

Comment: Sorry, I meant 0.2^-3 = 125

Comment: You can, but you will have to as is follows:
$$0.2=(0.2)^{-3\cdot \frac{-1}{3}}=((0.2)^{-3})^{\frac{-1}{3}}=125^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

so $0.2^{3-x}=125^{\frac{3-x}{-3}}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!